# Scalar curvature and second fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If one has a Riemannian manifold $M^3$ which is embedded in a $4$-manifold $N^4$ such that $M^3$ has metric $g$ and second fundamental form $k$, does having scalar curvature $R_g$ always larger than or equal to zero necessarily imply that $k$ is zero?

If not, does it at least imply that the trace of the second fundamental form $k_i^i = 0$?

Comment: Isn't $M^3=S^3$ and $N^4=\mathbb{R}^4$ a counterexample to both statements?

Comment: Yes I actually just thought of exactly that before coming back to my computer.  I was also thinking $M^3$ as a cylinder for an even more obvious counterexample.